# How to find SUBARRAY OR of array

Tags: python

Given an array of integers A of size N.

Value of a subarray is defined as BITWISE OR of all elements in it.

Return the sum of Value of all subarrays of A % 109 + 7.

Input `A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

```
Value([1]) = 1
 Value([1, 2]) = 3
 Value([1, 2, 3]) = 3
 Value([1, 2, 3, 4]) = 7
 Value([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) = 7
 Value([2]) = 2
 Value([2, 3]) = 3
 Value([2, 3, 4]) = 7
 Value([2, 3, 4, 5]) = 7
 Value([3]) = 3
 Value([3, 4]) = 7
 Value([3, 4, 5]) = 7
 Value([4]) = 4
 Value([4, 5]) = 5
 Value([5]) = 5
 Sum of all these values = 71
```

Code is below

```
def solve(a):
        n = len(a)
        mod = 10 ** 9 + 7
        sum2 = 0;
        for i in range(n):
            sum1 = 0
            for j in range(i, n):
                sum1 = (sum1 | a[j]);
                sum2 = sum2 + sum1;
        return sum2 % mod;
```

I got error Time Limit Exceeded. For small array i am getting correct output

How to reduce to TIME complexity.

Logic is how much contribution each set bet
ex: `[5, 9, 14]`

Subarays are
OR of [5] = 5 (0101)

OR of [9] = 9 (1110)

OR of[14] = 14 (1001)

OR of [5,9] = 15 (0101 + 1110 = 1111)

OR of [9,14] = 15 (1111)

OR of [5,9,14] = 15 (1111)

```
5 setbits are 1 at 3rd bit = 5x2**3
5 setbits are 1 at 2nd bit = 5x2**2
4 setbits are 1 at 1st bit = 5x2**1
5 setbits are 1 at 0th bit = 5x2**0
```

5x2^3 + 5x2^2 + 4x2^1 + 5x2^0 = 71

Below code using bit wise also giving me time limit exceed error

```
def solve(a):
        mod = 10 ** 9 + 7
        n = len(a)
        ans = 0
        for i in range(32):
            ind = n
            for j in range(n-1, -1,-1):
                bit = bool((a[j] >> i) &1)
                if bit:
                    ind = j
                ans += (n-ind)*pow(2,i)  
    
        return ans % mod   
solve([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Even the above code also gave a Time limit exceed error

Comment: Out of curiosity: whats the question? Where do you get the `Time Limit Exceeded` error?

Comment: This sounds like a problem on leetcode or a similar application, can you link the problem I'm not sure that I understand your explaination.

Comment: @Zaiborg you have it on the post. You only have to add an "How can" before. The question is: "how can I return the sum of Value of all subarrays of A % 109 + 7?"

Comment: for each number calculate the occurence of each bit in total subarrays you need to handle if a bit is duplicated by another number and only calculate the value once in that subarray n*log2(n)

Comment: @Zaiborg, This is not a python error. Programming puzzle websites like leet code restrict the amount of time your code can run to disallow brute-force answers to the puzzle (and prevent people from clogging up their servers with infinite loops).

Comment: @Andrew-Harelson https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jp85hoo0rzo

Comment: Hi @abd , have you seen my answer? I actually think it will help you.. please take a look at it if you didn't already, and give me some feedbacks. If you find it helpful, I'll be so delighted  to give my answer an upvote  or even choose it as the correct answer ✅. Cheers.

Comment: @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam 2 things, I want to use python only and i need code to solve above problem. Logic is how much contribution each set bet is given to reduce the 2 loops

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are running your code on a server which has set some limitations for `execuation time`, such as [`competitive programming`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_programming) contests.

This link explains the reasons why you might get the `Time Limit Exceed` error and how to handle it:
[How to overcome Time Limit Exceed(TLE)?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overcome-time-limit-exceedtle/)

---

##### Overcome Time Limit Errors

- Change methods of Input-Output

  > - This methods are only used for `C/C++` and `Java` programming languages, and there isn't any faster way to input or output in `Python`
- Bounds of loops may be reduced

  > - Read the bounds in the input carefully before writing your program.
  > - Figure out which inputs will cause your program to run slower.
  > - If a problem tells you that `N <= 100000` , and your program has nested loops each which go up to N, your program will never be fast enough.
- Optimize your Algorithm

  > - If nothing works after all this, then you should try changing the algorithm or the approach you are using to solve your problem.
- Look for Suggestions given

  > - Look at the comments given below, any problem in which other programmers might have given a hint on how the problem can be solved better and more efficiently hinted at
  > - When you overcome `TLE` try more exhaustive and corner test cases against your program to check the performance.

---

I highly suggest to use `C++` programming language for this type of contests.

Answer (score 0):

Use mod in the right place

```py
def solve(a):
        mod = 10 ** 9 + 7
        n = len(a)
        ans = 0
        for i in range(32):
            ind = n
            for j in range(n-1, -1,-1):
                bit = bool((a[j] >> i) &1)
                if bit:
                    ind = j
                ans = (ans + ((n-ind)*pow(2,i,mod)) % mod) % mod  
        return ans
```

Comment: is in it the same ans i have posted apart from % mod, its still same issue

Comment: mod plays a huge part in speed, try to test your solution with big numbers vs this solution,  what are the limit for the numbers inside the array, can you try to reduce the 32 range ?

Comment: Yes, I have changed its not the appropriate solution. I tried. Is there any way that 1 0 0 1, we have to substract n(n+1)/ 2 since second fro total array for the continuous 0

Answer (score 0):

```
def solve(self, A):
    n = len(A)
    ans = 0
    p2 = 1
    for i in range(30):
        ind  = n
        for j in reversed(range(n)):
            #bit = bool((A[j]>>i)&1)
            bit = bool(A[j] & p2)
            if bit:
                ind = j
            ans += (n-ind)*(p2)
        p2 *= 2
    return ans %(10**9+7)
```

This will not give TLE.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).